# Best way to modify objects declared in other classes (Java)

Tags: java, class, object

I'm making a tic tac toe game for a class, and the player must be an oject.  I'm using windowbuilder for the GUI, and in that, we must modify the player's name (part of the player object).  In another class seperate from the player and menu class, we must access the player's obect to grab the name using a getter, to display it on the screen.  I need to know how to modify an object from another class.

A constructor in the player class:

```
    public Player(String player, int initialGamesWon) {
    playerName = player;
    gamesWon = initialGamesWon;
}
```

What happens in the menu when we press start:

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            GameBoard game = new GameBoard();
            game.main(null);
            String newPlayerName = playersName.getText();
            Player player1 = new Player(newPlayerName);

        }
```

In the menu code here, we are not using the default constructor, but it is similar, it just sets the initial games to 0.
In the game board code, the label we want to be the player's name:

```
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(player1.getPlayerName());
```

This is where we get the error, as the player1 object is undeclared in this class.

EDIT: We've gotten to the point where I can make a new player in the menu, and change its name, as shown by here:

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            GameBoard game = new GameBoard();
            game.main(null);
            String newPlayerName = playersName.getText();
            setPlayerName(newPlayerName);

        }
```

Here are other methods in the menu class which are applicable

```
    public void setPlayerName(String newName) {
    player1.changeName(playersName.getText());
}
public String getMenuName() {
    return player1.getPlayerName();
}
```

Here is my code from the game board, which is still not working:

```
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(getMenuName());
```

However, getMenuName isn't declared here.

Comment: Why don't you make Player object field in GUI class

Comment: Your game variable is still a **local** variable! Please re-read the answers. And you need to show more code. Not too much code but more. You're calling `getMenuName()` as if it is a method in the same class that holds your JLabel and we have no idea if it is or not, but the Java compiler is telling you (correctly) that it isn't. You can only call the method on an object whose class has that method.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Swing and all to do with core Java at its most basic, that of understanding variables, references, and methods. For instance if a class has the `getMenuName()`, and you need to call this method, you need to call it on an *instance* of that class. You can't call it on nothing as you're trying to do. Get the necessary variable in there where you need it and then call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GUI needs a `setPlayer1Name(String name)` method and your Player class needs a get and set method for the playerName field. The Control class will get the name from the user, will set the Player's name. The Control can then set the GUI's display of the name, or if the GUI (the view) has a listener attached to the Player, it can automatically set the name when the Player's name is set or changed.

Note that your problem with this code is:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
     GameBoard game = new GameBoard(); // **** local variable
     game.main(null);
     String newPlayerName = playersName.getText();
     Player player1 = new Player(newPlayerName); // **** local variable
}
```

You're declaring two key variables as local to the method -- they're completely invisible to the rest of the program, and this obviously will never work. You need to use fields here, not local variable.s

So instead do,....

```
public class FooClass {
   private Player player1;
   private GameBoard game;
   private JTextField playersName;
   private JLabel lblNewLabel1 = new JLabel();

   public FooClass() {
      JButton button = new JButton("Start");
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            game = new GameBoard(); // field
            game.main(null);
            String newPlayerName = playersName.getText();
            player1 = new Player(newPlayerName); // field
            lblNewLabel1.setText(newPlayerName); // set label
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: What would be in the gui's method?  I tried this, to no avail.  At some point I have to specify which player in the menu, which'll cause an error.

Comment: @Cflo: see edit. Your basic code structure is broken. Of course the JLabel code can't see player1 because you've declared it local to the actionPerformed method. Don't do this. Declare the variable as a private field in the class.

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft, I have done this in the menu class. Now how would I access that object's getName method from the other class?  Running into the same error where now it isn't defined over there.

Comment: @Cflo: it's nothing more than having proper references to the classes you need to access and calling their methods. Just extend the ideas here to your other situation. If you have the same problem, use the same general solution to solve it. You can do this, I know you can!

Comment: I attempted to make a getter method for the menu gui, however I'm pretty new to this objects this and since this appears to have nothing to do with objects, the other class says the method is now undefined..

Comment: @Cflo: impossible to say what's wrong based on what you've stated. Edit your question.

Comment: In the menu gui, I have successfully made a new player and changed its name.  I have a new method that is a getter for this exact player object's name.  However, the method is uncallable in another class, so the getter doesn't work.

Comment: @Cflo: again edit your question, **show** your code. Let's not play the guess what my code shows game. Actually show it to us, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

they are 2 different classes, since you are creating an object of the class then you call it's variables or methods by using the new object you made, so:

```
Player player1 = new Player("player",0); // creating object
String PName = player1.playerName; //stores the name of player1 in PName.
System.out.println(player1.gamesWon); //outputs games won
```

if you want to change that name then you will need to create a method in the Player class that does that

```
public void reName(String newName)
{
  playerName = newName;
}
```

then call the method from the other class

```
Player player1 = new Player("player",0); // creating object
player1.reName("Awesome");
```

any method that you will need to use to change or use the Player class goes in that class, then you just call the methods.. you can reset the score or rename or do anything in that class, just create a method and then call it.

Comment: But this doesn't say how I'd modify that string from a different class

Comment: sorry, got distracted and forgot to add it, did it help?

Comment: The problem is still there.  I've successfully changed the name, but now I can't access it outside of this class.

Comment: what do you mean cannot access it outside the class? which class?? as i explained you can access it using the object you created,, or you can create a method that returns it.. something like `public string getName(){return playerName;}`